# Texstudio macro to change selection to inside of bracekts

Tags: texstudio

I am trying to make a TexStudio macro that expands the selection to the interior of any surrounding braces. So for instance if the cursor is somewhere in `name` in `\label{name}` it would select `name`.

(If there is no `{}` around the cursor at all it would do nothing.)

I can find how to act on the selected text but not how to change the selection in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This first basic answer is generic for selecting one word whether it is inside braces or not it is in effect the same as the existing shortcut Ctrl+D

In the Macro scripts editor press <kbd>Add</kbd>
Give it a name such as **`SelectWord`**
Chose a <kbd>shortcut</kbd> combination and enter

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.select(cursorEnums.WordUnderCursor)
```

> NOTE if the word is "paired" such as
>
> \begin{documentum}
>   \end{documentum}
>
> as normal for TXS editing one will highlight both and edits to one change both matching words at the same time.

To be more useful (and dangerous)
You could add a second variant such as **ClearWord** to save hitting the delete key

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.select(cursorEnums.WordUnderCursor)
cursor.removeSelectedText()
cursor.clearSelection()
```

Beware the same "pairing" will clear both braced entries ready for replacement.

The above simple versions only work with a single word however if you want a more complex version to **{SelectAll}** or {DeleteAll} e.g. {**`Goodbye World`**} you will need this version

```
%SCRIPT
// grab the line the cursor is on
var ln = cursor.lineNumber();
var tl = editor.text(ln);

// get text before and after cursor
var beforeText = tl.substr(0, cursor.columnNumber());
var afterText = tl.substr(cursor.columnNumber(), tl.length);

// search for last { before cursor, and first } after cursor
var lh = beforeText.lastIndexOf('\{');
var rh = afterText.indexOf('\}');
if (lh>=0 && rh>=0){
// match found, select everything between the {braced pair}
cursor.selectColumns(lh+1, rh+cursor.columnNumber())
// To delete everything between the braces uncomment the next two lines
// cursor.removeSelectedText()
// cursor.clearSelection()
}
```